# MongoDB is db.update easiest way to update record you already have?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database, nosql

I needed to read a record from `mongo` and add a new field based on information from this record (so I could not do `db.my.update()` right away) and I came up with this code:

```
var id = '5711298cf896b24fa1529d8e';
var cursor = db.my.find({_id: ObjectId(id)})

if (cursor.count() > 0) {
    var rec = cursor.next();

    var id = rec._id.valueOf()

    db.my.update({_id: ObjectId(id)}, {$set: {newField: 777}});
}
```

It works but I am looking at it and wonder is it really cleanest way to do it?
I would expect something like

```
var id = '5711298cf896b24fa1529d8e';
var cursor = db.my.find({_id: ObjectId(id)})

if (cursor.count() > 0) {
    var rec = cursor.next();
    rec.newField = 777;
    db.my.update(rec); // or even rec.save();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can't you simply do `db.my.update({_id: ObjectId('5711298cf896b24fa1529d8e')}, {$set: {newField: 777}});`?

Comment: @chridam I gave answer to it in first line of my question.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to create a cursor first, the [**`update`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db-collection-update) operator will use the query as selection criteria for the update. The same query selectors as in the [**`find()`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) method are available so the cursor is not necessary

Comment: @chridam, Sorry I didn't get it, could you, please, show code example?

Comment: You can just do `db.my.update({_id: ObjectId('5711298cf896b24fa1529d8e')}, {$set: {newField: 777}});`

Comment: @chridam Ok, I tried to answer why I am not doing it in this way but  probably I was not clear. i just added an answer including answer to this question :)

Comment: @chridam Imagine I do something like this `rec[rec.status + '_' + rec.role] = rec.accessRights`, it looks odd but real world case could have more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I am still not sure that it is the best solution but I figured out how to make ti look better

```
var id = '5711298cf896b24fa1529d8e';

var cursor = db.my.find({_id: ObjectId(id)})

if (cursor.count() > 0) {
    var rec = cursor.next();
    rec.newField = 777;
    db.my.save(rec);
}
```

I would come to this earlier but for some reason Robomongo confused me - if you modify `rec` and `print()` it - it does not show _id anymore so I didn't know why is that. It appeared original `mongo` console does not do that.

Also I would like to clarify again: I do understand that I could do it right away in this fashion

```
db.my.update({_id: ObjectId('5711298cf896b24fa1529d8e')}, {$set: {newField: 777}});
```

but my in case I wanted to learn how to work with record if you got if from cursor, for cases like when you need to modify record based on data from that record, like extract something and put it in separate field.